# UIImagePickerController video maximun size

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a **UIImagePickerController** to record a video and I need a video with max duration of **30 sec** or max size of **40 MB**. By default i have set it **videoMaximumDuration**, but I don't know how to restrict the maximum size of a video and is there any idea to limit a video size?

Comment: I think You cannot limit video size because user can select any size of video. You can compress it before sending to server.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this library   https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

```
let maxDuration:Float64 = 60
let videoDuration = asset!.duration
let videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration)

   if videoDurationSeconds > maxDuration {
       if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideoAtPath(asset!.URL.path!) {
              let videoEditor = UIVideoEditorController()
              self.videoEditor.videoPath = asset!.URL.path!
              self.videoEditor.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0
              self.presentViewController(self.videoEditor, animated: true, completion: nil)

             }

         }


// MARK: - UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate

func videoEditorController(editor: UIVideoEditorController, didSaveEditedVideoToPath editedVideoPath: String) { 

                 self.videoEditor.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                            //Do whatever you wish with the trimmed video here
                        }
```